# IndexError: list index out of range but the program working

Tags: python

I need to change a nucleotide in a DNA. So I want to change DA to DG. I wrote the following program. The program is partially work but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DNA.py", line 18, in <module>
    if NUM != line.split()[5]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know I have a problem in the following section but I can not find the reason.

```
for line in lines:
    if NUM != line.split()[5]:
      OT.writelines(line)
```

I would be happy if you can let me know.
Thanks

Comment: `print len(line.split()) <= 5`

Comment: _"I wrote the following program"_. Ok, let's see it.

Comment: It would be much better if you posted more code. The code you gave us doesnt really help

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: *list index out of range*

That means that the `5` in this line is too big: `if NUM != line.split()[5]`.

You should do the split on a separate line, save the results, and then only use the 5th element if the result actually has that many elements.  For example:

```
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) >= 6 and NUM != words[5]:
      OT.writelines(line)
```

If you *think* that the data is correct, you should validate your assumptions by putting a print statement inside the loop so that you can see what `line` is for every iteration. If the data is correct you definitely will *not* get the error you say you do. The only possible explanation<sup>1</sup> is that the data isn't what you expect.

<sup>1</sup>That's not literally true. You could get the error if `lines` is a list of custom objects, and that each object has a custom `split` method that returns something different. That scenario is highly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks. The line has 11 column. So I am sure that it has 10 index. line.split() itself is working well but when I change it to "NUM != line.split()[5]" it makes error. Thats why I am confusing!!!

Comment: Are you _assuming_ the line has 11 columns, or do you know for absolute certainty that `line` has 11 columns? Maybe you have a blank line. Python won't throw the error if the line does indeed have the data you says it does, so the only explanation is that the data _isn't_ what you think it is.

Comment: No i dont. the line is as follow:


"ATOM      8  N   SER X   2      41.940  59.452  98.178  0.00  0.00"

Comment: @MortezaKhabiri: with all due respect, that's impossible. If the data in `line` is what you say it is, the split will return 11 items and you absolutely, unquestionably will _not_ get the error you say you do. You should put a print statement inside the loop to print out every line. I think you'll find there's a line that is blank, or shorter than you think.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and reply. Actually you are right. It seem not logic, thats why I am confusing. I think I found the problem. I had a balnk line at last, thats why I was getting error.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> str1= "1 2 3 4 5 6"
>>> str2= "1 2 3 4 5"
>>> print str1.split()[5]
6
>>> print str2.split()[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If your space-separated line does not have enough columns, it will raise the IndexError

You can always check the length before use the column:
columns = line.split()

```
if len(columns) >= 6:
    # find a better name for column6...
    column6 = columns[5]
    # do your work
else:
    # do nothing
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. The line has 11 column. So I am sure that it has 10 index. line.split() itself is working well but when I change it to "NUM != line.split()[5]" it makes error. Thats why I am confusing!!!

Comment: what is the field separator, is it space separated?  `line.split()` uses space separator as default

Comment: Yes .. it is space separator as follow: 
ATOM      6  C   PRO X   1      40.788  59.290  98.901  0.00  0.00
ATOM      7  O   PRO X   1      39.747  58.752  98.465  0.00  0.00
ATOM      8  N   SER X   2      41.940  59.452  98.178  0.00  0.00

Comment: it may contains blank lines or lines columns less than 6.  you can check it out by printing the lines which `len(columns) < 6`

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply and also your clue. As you said I had a blank line at the end of my file which made an error. Thanks alot for your help.